# How to get XML using AsyncTask and PublishProgress

Tags: android, xml, multithreading, saxparser, android-asynctask

I parse XML data and put it into an object. This takes fairly long and I have decided to run it in the background using AsyncTask. My code is almost exactly like this example:
[How to get XML using AsyncTask and Timer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2021880/how-to-get-xml-using-asynctask-and-timer)

The difference being that I want to PublishProgress as I go long. The relevant part of the code where I want to publish progress:

```
@Override   
public void endElement(String namespaceURI, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {       
        if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("client")) {         
            clients.addClient(mClient);
            // Publish Progress
            RotationAwareTask.publishProgress();
            mClient = null;
        }       
    }
```

By now you would have deduced that I am a novice. The closest research that matches what I want to do states:

http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg79275.html

> Yes, that is a bit more complex... Two
>   approaches:
>
> 1) Make AsyncTask implement
>   org.sax.ContentHandler. That way the
>   SAX callbacks have direct access to
>   AsyncTask.publishProgress().
>
> 2) Create a delegate so that the
>   parser has a handle back to AsyncTask
>   for posting progress updates.

When I try the above I get:

> The method
>   publishProgress(Progress...) from the
>   type AsyncTask is
>   not visible

Alas, how can I call publicProgress from endElement? Or could someone give me some how to do this properly? To recap:

I have XML data.
Reading the data is a long operation.
I use the SAXParser to get the data.
On the endElement method the data is added to an object which will eventually be used elsewhere.
Most research indicates I have to use AsyncTask and I am using that now because I have a good example from Commonsware for screen rotation.
The question is how to update progress as I go along.

Edit:
@Cristian here is the async task:

```
static class RotationAwareTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {        
        RotationAsync activity = null;      
        int progress = 0;       

        private SaxClientsHandler saxClientsHandler;

        RotationAwareTask(RotationAsync activity) {
            attach(activity);
        }

            @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {         
            try {
                SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
                SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
                XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
                saxClientsHandler = new SaxClientsHandler();
                xr.setContentHandler(saxClientsHandler);
                InputSource mSource = new InputSource( new StringReader( Whmcs.getClientsXml() ) );
                xr.parse(mSource);          
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
            }           
            return(null);       
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... unused) {
            if (activity==null) {
                Log.w("RotationAsync", "onProgressUpdate() skipped – no activity");
            }
            else {
                progress += 5;
                activity.updateProgress(progress);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
            if (activity == null) {
                Log.w("RotationAsync", "onPostExecute() skipped – no activity");
            }
            else {
                activity.markAsDone();
            }
        }

        void detach() {
            activity = null;
        }

        void attach(RotationAsync activity) {
            this.activity = activity;
        }

        int getProgress() {         
            return(progress);
        }

    }
```

This is almost an exact duplicate of this Commonsware example:
https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/blob/master/Rotation/RotationAsync/src/com/commonsware/android/rotation/async/RotationAsync.java

As you can see:

> saxClientsHandler = new
>   SaxClientsHandler();

calls the SaxClientHandler() where the endElement method exists. I am trying to publish the progress from there.

@Mayra, are you suggesting that I migrate all the saxClientHandler code into the AsyncTask?

Comment: Paste the async task you are using, and how you are trying to invoke the publishProgress method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing `RotationAwareTask.publishProgress();` `publishProgress` is not a static method, you need to call it on the instance of `RotationAwareTask`.

Comment: Thank you Mayra! The key was to copy the SaxClientsHandler() code into the RotationAwareTask as you suggested. I wasn't aware that you could nest classes like that. In fact I didn't even know where to start looking and I have been battling with this for at least a week.