# parse xml after some time android

Tags: android, xml-parsing

In my app i need to parse the XML file & display info on activity. just like stock market as & when information at server got updated i need to parse the xml & display the info.I need to hit the server after 5 minutes & display the updated info on activity. I have tried using AsyncTask & timer but something going wrong.If any one is having demo then please provide link,tutorial..

It's extermely urgent..

thnx for any help....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want to run a polling loop in the background? You should be able to use a timer to kick off the check and an async task to actually request/parse. There's a bit of complexity in setting up the timer handling, the accepted answer to this question should help however:

[How to get XML using AsyncTask and Timer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2021880/how-to-get-xml-using-asynctask-and-timer)